Fix missed Supermicro server power supply status via IPMI
We are experiencing an issue with the IPMI tool on several of our Supermicro servers. We have a script that monitors the status of power supplies by running the command ipmitool sdr type "Power Supply". The command typically returns output like this:
PS1 Status       | C8h | ok  | 10.88 | Presence detected
PS2 Status       | C9h | ok  | 10.87 | Presence detected

The script checks for the presence of "ok" and "Presence detected" in each line. This has been working well until recently.
The problem is that, from time to time, the command output lacks the "Presence detected" part, causing the script to fail. For example, the output might look like this:
PS1 Status       | C8h | ok  | 10.88 |
PS2 Status       | C9h | ok  | 10.87 |

We attempted to resolve this by performing a BMC cold reset using the command ipmitool mc reset cold. However, this resulted in the complete removal of any power supply status lines from the output. It appears that during the BMC reboot, some BMC software "modules", such as the power supply status module, are not initialized properly. We were only able to restore the functionality by disconnecting the server from power (both power supplies) and then power on the server it after a few minutes. When work remotely this become quite stressing and sometime hard to do (e.g. lack of remote hands in reach).
My question is: How can we ensure that the BMC/IPMI consistently returns the power supply status, or how can we reinitialize its modules so that they start working again without needing to power cycle the server?

This is either firmware or hardware issue. You have to resolve it with your vendor. We can't help here. Also bear in mind this is Supermicro, a low cost, with the corresponding quality of support. Consider using ipmiutil; in my experience, it decoded Supermicro BMC event logs better, maybe it'll help here too.

@NikitaKipriyanov thank you for this tip, will try to. We used to use ipmitool for years and no problem so far except for this tiny one. For me, the best way is to use supermicro's IPMICFG, but even such utility fails to return uniform reply on different servers, so parsing its output on any server is tricky a bit anyway.

I know, and still suggest you to consider using ipmiutil. I was using ipmitool for years too, until I've got to find out which PSU failed and when (it wasn't supermicro though, it was Intel S5520 mobo and I don't remember what else). And it turned out that only ipmiutil decoded logs into something meaningful. Likewise, on some other machine, memory module started throwing mce exceptions, and ipmitool simply wasn't able to tell what slot it is in, whereas ipmiutil worked perfectly. So I still use ipmitool, but I always have ipmiutil at the ready.
